# Cucumber signing in isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber

I can sign in with my browser but Cucumbe can't sign in.

My users/sign_out route accepts GET.

features/step_denfinitions/home_page_steps.rb:

```
When(/^I am on the homepage$/) do
  visit root_path
end

Then (/^I should see "(.*?)"$/) do |t|
  assert page.has_content?(t)
end

Given (/^I am signed in$/) do
  visit ('/users/sign_out')
  email = 'game@maker.com'
  password = 'password'
  visit '/users/sign_in'
  fill_in "user_email", :with => email
  fill_in "user_password", :with => password
  click_button "Sign in"
end

And(/^I go to home page$/) do
  visit root_path 
end
```

features/home_page.feature:

```
Feature: Home page

  Scenario: Viewing home page
    Given I am on the homepage
    Then I should see "Hello"

  Scenario: Signed in can create a game
    Given I am signed in
    Then I should see "Create Game"
```

/app/views/welcome/index.html (my root path):

```
<h1>Welcome#index</h1>
"Hello"
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>

  <% if user_signed_in? %> <<< This works in my browser but not for cucumber
    <%= link_to "Create Game", new_game_path %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Put a `sleep 100` on the lowest line in your steps that you think you get to. When you run Cuke, what does the browser reveal when you are on that line. (Your post contains no symptoms, only harmless code. Also, you shouldn't bother with Capybara until you have Rails & RSpec working, round-trip. AND most Cucumber tests should access your Ruby code directly, without going through a browser. But...)

Comment: @Philip Cucumber is running headlessly. By "browser" I meant I rails s and load the page myself to take a look.

Comment: Testing in my browser, If I'm already signed in the sign_in page won't load. But if I'm signed in, I shoudl see "Create Game"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Cucumber doesn't actually sign in with a real user.. I have to create the user on the fly.

[Testing login with devise and cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466045/testing-login-with-devise-and-cucumber)